# AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'pin_message'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, helper

Erro: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'pin_message'
It's doing this erro, and I dont understand why.
Can anyone help me with this
Thankful

```
global stopcheck
stopcheck = 'test'
import asyncio
global time
time = 100
import os
ContinueAutoJoke = 'autojoke'
StopAutoJoke = 'o'
import discord
import time
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands



client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  message = await ctx.send(f'All messages gonna be deleted in 100 seconds')
  await client.pin_message(message)
  for c in range(-100,0):
      await message.edit(content=f'All messages gonna be deleted in {c} seconds')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`discord.Message.pin()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=pin#discord.Message.pin), not `client.pin_message(message)`:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send(f'All messages gonna be deleted in 100 seconds')
    await message.pin()
    for c in range(-100,0):
        await message.edit(content=f'All messages gonna be deleted in {c} seconds')
        asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.purge(limit=100)
```